# SELECT value x WHERE x has same unknown value AND WHERE value y is in array

Tags: mysql, sql, select, relational-division

I have a table that stores product groups.

```
table "products_groups"

id  |  id_group | id_product
============================
 1  |  1        | 1
 2  |  1        | 2
 3  |  1        | 3
 4  |  2        | 1
 5  |  2        | 2
 6  |  3        | 2
```

I need a SQL query that will find the id_group that contains all id_product's that are in the given array.

```
product_ids = array(1);       // should return no results
product_ids = array(1,2);     // should only return id_group 2
product_ids = array(1,2,3);   // should only return id_group 1
product_ids = array(1,2,3,4); // should return no results
```

I played/searched around, ended up stuck at

```
SELECT p1.id_group
FROM products_groups p1, products_groups p2
WHERE p1.id <> p2.id
AND p1.id_group = p2.id_group
AND (
    p1.id_product = 1 
    OR p1.id_product = 2
    OR p1.id_product = 3
)
```

But it obviously is not giving me the result I am looking for. I don't know if I am thinking too simple or too complex.

Notes: Of course the id_product values will be dynamically generated in the SQL. It will eventually be used with PHP/Codeigniter

Background info: Each product has a price, but products can be in a product group which has a package price. That is why I need to know for each order if the products are in a group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is called `Relational Division`

```
SELECT  id_group
FROM    products_groups
WHERE   id_product IN (1,2)
GROUP   BY id_group
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

or something like this,

```
SELECT  id_group
FROM    products_groups
GROUP   BY id_group
HAVING  SUM(id_product IN (1,2)) = COUNT(*) AND
        COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/909da/5)

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks a lot! I will look into relational division.

Comment: and please to enforce a unique multiple column constraint on this column `id_group, id_product`.